# Best way to fetch a dynamic result set into a cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a reporting function that takes a SQL query and generates some aggregations and transformations on it. All the queries return columns with the structure: ID, COL1, COl2, COL3.... COL25.

That function fetches the results into a cursor in order to process them, storing the row in a variable as follows:

as follows:

```
    OPEN C1 FOR V_SQL;
        LOOP
            CASE COLUMN_COUNT
                WHEN 3 THEN
                    FETCH C1 INTO ROW.C1,ROW.C2,ROW.C3;
                WHEN 4 THEN
                    FETCH C1 INTO ROW.C1,ROW.C2,ROW.C3,ROW.C4;
                WHEN 5 THEN
                    FETCH C1 INTO ROW.C1,ROW.C2,ROW.C3,ROW.C4,ROW.C5;
                ... (until 29 columns)
```

Now 'm required to support up to 100 columns. This would make the code very large. How can I accomplish this in a dynamic way, like an array?

Comment: Take a look at the oracle [DBMS_SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sql.htm#i1027602) package for dynamic sql.

Comment: This is a good learning task for a *young programmer*  @OldProgrammer, thanks for the inspiration;)

Answer (score 1):

This procedure receives a SQL query text (from a secure source - note that otherwise you should implement some basic checks for malicious code) along with a number of columns you want to fetch.

The procedure parse the query, defines dynamically teh columns in the required count and fetches the rows to produce DBMS_OUTPUT - you should get the idea for your use case.

You may omit the `col_cnt` parameter and get the value from the cursor using `DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS`, but this will required additional open / close of the cursor.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ftch ( 
     sql_txt      IN VARCHAR2, 
     col_cnt      IN NUMBER) IS 

     type array_vc_t is varray(100) of varchar2(30);     
     id                 NUMBER; 
     cols               array_vc_t := array_vc_t(); 
     source_cursor      INTEGER;  
     ignore             INTEGER; 
  BEGIN 

     source_cursor := dbms_sql.open_cursor; 
     DBMS_SQL.PARSE(source_cursor,sql_txt, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE); 

     DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(source_cursor, 1, id); 
     for i in 1..col_cnt loop
          cols.extend();     
          DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(source_cursor, i+1, cols(i), 30); 
     end loop; 
     ignore := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(source_cursor); 

     LOOP 
       IF DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS(source_cursor)>0 THEN 

         DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(source_cursor, 1, id); 
         for i in 1..col_cnt loop
             DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(source_cursor, i+1, cols(i)); 
         end loop;
         dbms_output.put_line('id= '|| id );
         for i in 1..col_cnt loop
             dbms_output.put_line('        i='|| i || ' col = '|| cols(i)  );
         end loop;         
      ELSE 

  -- No more rows - exit
        EXIT; 
      END IF; 
    END LOOP; 

     DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(source_cursor); 
   EXCEPTION 
     WHEN OTHERS THEN 
       IF DBMS_SQL.IS_OPEN(source_cursor) THEN 
         DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(source_cursor); 
       END IF; 
       RAISE; 
  END; 
/
```

example

```
exec ftch('select id, col1, col2 from tab',2);
```

output

```
id= 1
        i=1 col = xx1
        i=2 col = xx2
id= 2
        i=1 col = yy1
        i=2 col = yy2
id= 3
        i=1 col = zz1
        i=2 col = zz2
```